# Setting httpOnly cookies in cross-domain requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios

Is is possible to set httpOnly cookies on a browser when the server and client are on completely different domains (not subdomains)? The mechanism works when both my server and client are on http://localhost, but the cookie isn't even set in the browser when I move them to separate domains. I've tried adding the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the server but it still doesn't work.
I have a React front end app and a Node backend both hosted on different domains. Does the cookie mechanism only work if your app is monolithic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the domain you are sending the request from. Let's say you are calling the api from [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) then "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" should have the value [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com). Having * for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" won't work. What is your current value for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ?

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is set to "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: can you console and check what you are getting in req.headers.origin ?

Comment: req.headers.origin is undefined. But the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is set on Postman

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be set on the server side in your response headers.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set on the server side. I meant that when I make a request from Postman, I can see it among the headers. But when I log req.headers.origin on the server, I get undefined

Comment: could you paste the curl requests from the browser and from postman here? Comparing them could help find the issue.